# NSNotFound, NSInteger, NSUInteger, and NSRange.location

Tags: cocoa, compare

`NSNotFound` is defined as `NSIntegerMax`, which is defined as `LONG_MAX`.

`NSRange.location` is defined as a `NSUInteger`.

Some Foundation methods return an `NSRange` whose location value is `NSNotFound`.

So, one often does this comparison:

```
if (aRange.location == NSNotFound)
```

But isn't that a comparison between signed and unsigned integers that should generate a warning?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are comparing an unsigned (64 bit) variable with a signed *constant* which also fits into the range of the variable (it is not negative). So no need for a warning.

The warnings appear typically when comparing against negative constants or variables on both sides (i.e. one part is or can be negative while the other is only positive or zero).

A side note: NSNotFound is different on 32 bit vs 64 bit platforms, so don't hardcode or store that value anywhere.